# Computing effect for each firm for one of the explanatory variable in the panel data (Stata)

Tags: stata, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I have panel data with firms $i=1,...,N$ and year $t=1,...,T$. Also, assume that I have the model like below:

$y_{it}=\beta x_{1it}+\alpha_{i}x_{2it}+v_{i}+u_{it}$

My simple question is how to estimate $\alpha_{i}$. Note that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are continuous variables.

In Stata, I did like below:

```
xtset firm year
reg y x1 i.firm#c.x2 i.firm
```

Is this the correct way to estimate $\alpha_{i}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a particular model, a fixed effects model. If that is what you want then that is an ok way of estimating it *in case of a linear model*. It is equivalent to using `xtreg` with the `fe` option, as you can see in the example below.

```
// create some example data
clear
set obs 25
gen firm = _n
gen firm_err = rnormal()
expand 10
bys firm : gen t = _n
gen err = rnormal()
gen byte x1 = runiform() < .5
gen x2 = rnormal()
gen y = 1 + x1 + (-1 -.5*firm)*x2 + .5*firm_err + .5*err

// use regress
reg y x1 ibn.firm#c.x2 i.firm, hascons

// use xtreg
xtset firm t
xtreg y x1 i.firm#c.x2, fe
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. You want to use `xtreg` or `areg`, depending on what assumptions you're willing to make.

---

**A response to Maarten Buis' comment**

"Correct way to estimate" is pretty vague. For point estimates, I absolutely agree with you. But if you interpret that broadly to include standard errors and computational considerations, I would disagree.

For standard errors, the areg/xtreg approach might be sometimes preferred. areg relies on different asymptotics: the number of groups cannot increases with the sample size. State or county dummies would be a nice example. There also might even be cases where `xtreg, re` might be chosen over `xtreg, fe` (though this is fairly unlikely) for efficiency reasons.

There are also computational reasons to consider. What if there are 100,000,000 firms? Would reg with the dummies approach be feasible or advisable?

This is why I wrote "probably not".

Here's a simple example to illustrate these points:

```
. webuse nlswork
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. reg ln_wage tenure hours i.idcode if idcode<10

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      96
-------------+------------------------------           F(  9,    86) =   10.57
       Model |  6.53208993     9   .72578777           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  5.90543027    86  .068667794           R-squared     =  0.5252
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.4755
       Total |  12.4375202    95  .130921265           Root MSE      =  .26205

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      tenure |   .0366445   .0073742     4.97   0.000     .0219852    .0513038
       hours |   .0111317   .0056074     1.99   0.050    -.0000154    .0222789
             |
      idcode |
          2  |  -.4341972   .1080463    -4.02   0.000    -.6489862   -.2194082
          3  |  -.5325276   .1024175    -5.20   0.000    -.7361268   -.3289284
          4  |  -.1049206   .1099367    -0.95   0.343    -.3234676    .1136263
          5  |  -.2051351   .1095512    -1.87   0.065    -.4229157    .0126454
          6  |  -.4924271   .1134483    -4.34   0.000     -.717955   -.2668993
          7  |  -.7081695   .1203409    -5.88   0.000    -.9473993   -.4689396
          9  |  -.2727572   .1192756    -2.29   0.025    -.5098693   -.0356451
             |
       _cons |   1.556582   .2301081     6.76   0.000     1.099143    2.014022
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtreg ln_wage tenure hours if idcode <10, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =        96
Group variable: idcode                          Number of groups   =         8

R-sq:  within  = 0.2664                         Obs per group: min =         8
       between = 0.0772                                        avg =      12.0
       overall = 0.1844                                        max =        15

                                                F(2,86)            =     15.62
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.1423                        Prob > F           =    0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      tenure |   .0366445   .0073742     4.97   0.000     .0219852    .0513038
       hours |   .0111317   .0056074     1.99   0.050    -.0000154    .0222789
       _cons |   1.215811   .2244351     5.42   0.000     .7696486    1.661973
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .23850178
     sigma_e |   .2620454
         rho |  .45306806   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0:     F(7, 86) =     8.78               Prob > F = 0.0000
```

These slope parameters and their standard errors are identical. Now we try to fit the dummies method with he full sample:

```
. reg ln_wage tenure hours i.idcode
matsize too small
    You have attempted to create a matrix with too many rows or columns or attempted to fit a model with too many variables.  You need to increase matsize; it is currently 400.  Use set
    matsize; see help matsize.

    If you are using factor variables and included an interaction that has lots of missing cells, either increase matsize or set emptycells drop to reduce the required matrix size; see
    help set emptycells.

    If you are using factor variables, you might have accidentally treated a continuous variable as a categorical, resulting in lots of categories.  Use the c. operator on such variables.
r(908);

end of do-file

r(908);
```

To be fair, you could increase the matsize to something larger and get away with OLS.

Comment: `xtreg` with the `fe` option is equivalent to `regress` with firm indicator variables. This only works with linear models, but that is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Dimitriy: Thanks for the clarification. I don't have the large number of firms and so I am okay with any approach.

Comment: The difference in standard errors are due to the fact that you compare different models: a fixed effects model with `reg` and a random effects model with `xtreg` without the `fe` option.

Comment: @MaartenBuis You're absolutely right! I must have lost my mind. Thanks for spotting that.